# Do I get to order the outcome of a voting card on the stack in the way I want?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, mtg-stack

If I play [Cirdan the Shipwright](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cirdan%20the%20Shipwright) its ETB triggers and everybody votes. If I receive no votes and have [Consecrated Sphinx](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Consecrated%20Sphinx) in hand, do I get to order the results of the vote in such a way, that I may put it into play first and get to draw a bunch of cards of it?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

**You can't order the actions required by Cirdan's ability, but you don't have to, the combo will work anyway. If you received no votes and put the Sphinx on the battlefield, it will trigger off any Cirdan card draws by your opponents.**

The votes are taken in APNAP order, i.e. clockwise around the table starting with the active player. The resulting actions (drawing a card or putting a permanent on the battlefield in your case) then happen at the same time:

> 101.4. If multiple players would make choices and/or take actions at the same time, the active player (the player whose turn it is) makes any choices required, then the next player in turn order (usually the player seated to the active player’s left) makes any choices required, followed by the remaining nonactive players in turn order. Then the actions happen simultaneously. This rule is often referred to as the “Active Player, Nonactive Player (APNAP) order” rule.
>
> *Example: A card reads “Each player sacrifices a creature.” First, the active player chooses a creature they control. Then each of the nonactive players, in turn order, chooses a creature they control. Then all creatures chosen this way are sacrificed simultaneously.*

So when your opponents draw their Cirdan card, the Sphinx is already on the battlefield. It will see each of those card draws and trigger for all of them.

Comment: The first ruling on Cirdan says that all the draws happen before anyone puts a permanent on the battlefield.

Comment: This is incorrect. Because they are separate sentences on Cirdan, all drawing all happens first and then a permanent is put into play by anyone who did not get a vote (and draw a card) Phillip's answer is correct, the combo does not work.

Answer (score 13):

No, you cannot make this happen; this is due to the way the card is worded:

> Whenever Círdan the Shipwright enters the battlefield or attacks, each player secretly votes for a player, then those votes are revealed.
>
> Each player draws a card for each vote they received.
>
> Each player who received no votes may put a permanent card from their hand onto the battlefield.

I've reformatted the text slightly to make it clear what happens:

1. Everybody votes (in APNAP order, not that it matters here as the votes are secret)
2. Draws happen for each player (in APNAP order)
3. Permanents go onto the battlefield (in APNAP order)

For what you want to happen, it would need to be worded something like "Each player draws a card for each vote received, or if they received no votes, may put a permanent card onto the battlefield from their hand".

Note this is covered in the first ruling on Gatherer:

> After the votes are revealed, first the player whose turn it is draws a card for each vote they received, then each other player in turn order does so. Then, if the first player received no votes, they may put a permanent card from their hand onto the battlefield. Then each other player in turn order does the same.